# different format String to date kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i have response which contains the date in the string.
the problem is that it has a different look in each item

```
  {
                "date" : "1990-01-07
            }, {
                "date" : "01-07-1990
            }, {
                "date" : "01-07-2003
            }, {
                "date" : "1990-01-07"
            }
```

how to translate it into date formats in that case?

what i tried:

```
val birthday = taskDataBase?.birthday

val yearPattern = "dd-MM-yyyy"
birthday?.let {
    when (it != "") {
        true -> { SimpleDateFormat(yearPattern).parse(it) }
        false -> { "- -"
        }
    }
}

val ageData = when(birthday == null || birthday.isNullOrEmpty()){
    true -> "- -"
    false -> birthday
}
```

but it doesn't give any result.
I need to get the date always of the same format, regardless of the format of the string
tnx

Comment: The best approach would be to fix the sender to use the same format in all cases.

Comment: @Henry I agree, but this is the server's response to the customer's request

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to just parse it twice in different formats:

```kotlin
val yearPattern1 = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
val yearPattern2 = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

val birthday = taskDataBase?.birthday
val birthdayDate = if (birthday.isNotEmpty()) {
    tryParse(birthday, yearPattern1) ?: tryParse(birthday, yearPattern2)
} else {
    null
}

...

fun tryParse(date: String, format: SimpleDateFormat): Date? = try {
    format.parse(date)
} catch (_: ParseException) {
    null
}
```